# Bluetooth headphones + bluetooth mouse = mouse lag

Tags: audio, mouse, linux-mint, bluetooth, lag

When I connect my Bluetooth headphones to my laptop (Linux Mint 18), they work fine. Same with my Bluetooth mouse. When both are connected, the mouse jitters and lags.

I'm using this Bluetooth adapter: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009ZIILLI/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009ZIILLI)

How can I stop my mouse lagging while using my headphones?

Comment: Don't know if it applies to you, but when we have 5GHZ wifi (at least in my scenario) it lags every bluetooth device connected to the computer. So, maybe there's some intensive wifi. Try to test with wifi off. Maybe is your turnaround.

Comment: i have the same *damn* issue when connecting a polycom headset and a logitech mx anywhere 3 mouse on windows 10!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different Bluetooth headphones solved my problem. I don't know why the first headphones caused this issue, but not all headphones do.

Answer (score 3):

it is the problem with bluetooth frequency, bluetooth 3.0 frequency interferes with mouse radio frequency and can cause both mouse and audio to lag, to fix this use bluetooth headphones with bluetooth version 4.0 or above, or use wired headphones or mouse keyboard, hope this helps, i was having the same problem just solved now
if it doesn't then turn your laptops or any devices bluetooth off